# How to check if an item already exists in table when inserting from a XML

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012

I need to insert data to  my table from XML. I have to check for uniqueness before inserting the data.

My current code is this:

```
@declare @existing_id INT=0

DELETE FROM [maintenance.master].[oper_cat]
WHERE  [oper_cat_id] IN (SELECT tab.col.value('Id[1]','int')  
                         FROM @oper_cat.nodes('//Sample') AS tab(col)
                         WHERE CAST(tab.col.value('Deleted[1]','bit') AS BIT) = 1)  

;WITH Sample AS
(   
    SELECT 
        tab.col.value('Id[1]','int') AS [Id],
        tab.col.value('Title[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS [Title],
        tab.col.value('Type[1]','char(1)') AS [Type],
    FROM  
        @oper_cat.nodes('//Sample') AS tab(col)  
    WHERE 
        CAST(tab.col.value('Deleted[1]','bit') AS BIT) = 0
) 
SET @existing_id = (SELECT id 
                    FROM sample_table 
                    WHERE title = Sample.Title AND type = Sample.Type)

IF  @existing_id = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO sample_table(id, title, type)
    VALUES(Sample.Id, Sample.Title, Sample.Type)
END
```

Obviously the above code is not working. I'm getting error when I'm trying to get the existing id. How can I check this before inserting the value into table. I'm not very good with SQL any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: First insert your XML data to a table_variable or temp_table and MERGE this with your actual table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
--a volatile table to get your XML row-wise
DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE(Id INT, Deleted BIT,Title VARCHAR(150),[Type] CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @tmpTable 
SELECT  tab.col.value('Id[1]','int') AS [Id],
        tab.col.value('Deleted[1]','bit') AS Deleted,
        tab.col.value('Title[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS [Title],
        tab.col.value('Type[1]','char(1)') AS [Type]
FROM  
    @oper_cat.nodes('//Sample') AS tab(col);  

--Delete all with Deleted=1
DELETE FROM [maintenance.master].[oper_cat]
WHERE  [oper_cat_id] IN (SELECT Id FROM @tmpTable WHERE Deleted=1);

--Insert all with Deleted=0
INSERT INTO sample_table(id, title, type)
SELECT Id,Title,[Type]
FROM @tmpTable 
WHERE Deleted=0;
```